# Python error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] on Windows 10 and Spyder

Tags: python, windows-10, ssl-certificate, spyder

When I last ran the code below in Jan 2021, on Spyder 3.x / Windows 10 it worked ok. When I tried to run it this week I get a host of errors leading to this final error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

Along the way of trying to sort the problem I updated from Spyder 3 to Spyder 5.1.5 though the problem persists.

I think this is the minium reproducible example:

```
import urllib.request
my_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(my_url).read()
print(html)
```

The problem is at the third line of the code. The print statement only verifies that we've got beyond that point. It occurs with some websites but not others, e.g. problem occurs if start_url = stackoverflow.com but not if I set it to 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'.

Interestingly the same code and error does not occur when I run it on Spyder 3.2.6 on Linux.

**The question:**

Any suggestions?

**Background info**

I've noticed there are a lot of questions about [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] errors on StackOverflow but I don't see how to apply their answers to my situation. Some are for Mac OS or for linux and sugggest typing

```
[path] Install\ Certificates.command
```

and so I don't know how to do this for Windows 10, let alone how to identify the path. I also found myself baffled with how to install PIP (suggesetd in some solutions) given the Anaconda/Spyder chain on Windows 10.

**Even more background**

I'm using Spyder IDE 5.1.5 and the Spyder help box has this to say about python etc:

```
Python 3.7.3 64-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10
```

Though I'm surprised it doesn't mention that I have Spyder installed via Anaconda. Further baffling  I see that when I type "python -version" in the windows cmd prompt I get the error:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store....
```

...which seems peculiar as Spyder is obviously running other python code ok.

Answer (score 0):

This issues is brought by by mostly the expiration of the old Let's Encrypt root certificates because they migrated to ISRG Root X1. You might try to install the valid certificates from https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/